# Deploy a WSP that is built on Teamsite to Publishing Site

Tags: solution-deployment

SharePoint 2013,
We have developed WSP for a TeamSite but due to requirement change client want to have publishing site. I wonder what I need to do to deploy the same WSP on Publishing Site in client's Machine.

Comment: Is that a sandbox solution you are asking about? Does it use any resources which are only available on a Team Site? How are you planning on deploying - farm wide or Solutions Gallery?

Comment: that is farm solution, that host a custom site page. It is going to be deployed on Farm solution. It doesn't use Team Site Resources.

Answer (score 1):

In your case WSP is deployed globally and not to a site collection (Solution Gallery) therefor you don't need to change or re-develop anything for your solution to work on a Publishing Site.

Comment: It is not globally deplyed, It is deployed at site collection level. I am getting error to activate the feature. Which deploy pages on SitePages. I changed the Element.xml but it doesn't work.

Comment: Earlier I had SitePages in element.xml. Now changed Sitepage to Pages. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature Id="23ac2eda-ccc6-4a15-8f40-d9f6755faa3f" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" ActivateOnDefault="TRUE" Scope="Web" Title="MY Feature">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="Pages\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Pages\MYHome.aspx" />
    <ElementFile Location="Pages\My.master" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Pages" Url=Pages">
    <File Path="Pages\MyHome.aspx" Url="MYHome.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Path="Pages\My.master" Url="My.master" />
  </Module>
</Elements>

Comment: It's a feature you are talking about, not the solution itself. What error do you get? And telling by the feature definition, it's scope is web, not site collection. By the way, master pages are usually deployed to Master Page gallery.

Comment: You are right but when was deploying the master page on Master Page Gallery it was not getting applied. Please share the code line to handle. I had resolved the deployment issue by changing the site to publishing and changing the module.xml

Comment: Could you please provide the code how you are applying your master page to the web site? Deploying it to the Masterpage library is not enough.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProjectNameFolder.Layouts.MyProjectName" 
MasterPageFile="../../../_catalogs/masterpage/ProjectMasterGallary/IWD.Master" %>

It throws error as below
Parser Error Message: The referenced file '/_catalogs/masterpage/ProjectMasterGallary/IWD.Master' is not allowed on this page.